# Given polynomials $f,g$ on an algebra $F$ and operators $T,D$ corresponding to integration/differentiation, show that $T[(Tf)g] = (Tf)(Tg) - T[f(Tg)]$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is as to whether there is an elegant way of demonstrating the desired result, without going through the nontrivial amount of computations required to attain the desired result. The exercise is reproduced below.

Let $F$ be a subfield of the complex numbers and let $T$, $D$ be the transformations on $F[x]$ defined by

$$ T \left( \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i \right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i}{1+i} x^{i+1}$$

and

$$ D \left( \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n i c_i x^{i-1}.$$

I am asked to show that $T[(Tf)g] = (Tf)(Tg) - T[f(Tg)]$.

Is there an elegant way to demonstrate this? I have considered viewing this exercise from the point of view of considering $T$ as integration of a function and looking for a shortcut, but I do not find anything recognizable in the form of the desired result.

The desired result does share some resemblance with the formula for integration by parts, but differs significantly. To prove this directly seems so computationally intensive that I have the feeling that there may be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove the statement in the title, here's a clue: by the product rule,
$$
D[(Tf)(Tg)] = (DTf)(Tg) + (Tf)(DTg) = f(Tg) + (Tf)g
$$
The similarity to integration by parts is no accident, because integration by parts is derived from the product rule.

Comment: This makes sense; thank you. However, it is not clear to me how easily one may "carry over" differentiation/integration rules from calculus to this situation. For example, the product rule for differentiation has not been defined for an algebra or for polynomials represented as vector spaces, at least in this text (Linear Algebra, by Hoffman and Kunze); is it generally acceptable to identify the given operators as differentiation/integration operators and then carry over the entire apparatus one learns in first-year calculus, or must one prove the same principles in this new context?

Comment: Furthermore, there is a step in the proof you suggested that I do not understand. If we apply $T$ from the left to the leftmost and rightmost sides of your equation, we achieve what we desire on the right hand side, but not necessarily on the left, because (as asked to be shown in a previous part of the same exercise) $TD \neq I$, even though $DT = I$ (where $I$ is identity). I do not see how to get around this, if beginning with your hint (which is much appreciated, by the way).

Comment: @user169845 If you know that $\{x^n\}$ defines a basis for $F[x]$, then it's easy enough to check that $D$ satisfies the Leibniz rule on basis elements, and hence, by linearity, on arbitrary vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By the Leibniz rule, do you mean the product rule for differentiation? If so, would you mind illustrating what you mean when you suggest to show that it holds for basis elements? I am not sure what you mean. I am sorry to ask what seems to me to be a basic question, but these concepts are new to me; I am not sure where to begin, and I would very much appreciate the direction, as I am self-studying. (I know the product rule, and I know that $\{x^n\}$ is a basis for $F[x]$, but I am not sure how to combine these in order to obtain what we are talking about.)

Comment: @user169845 By the Leibniz rule I mean the product rule. Suppose you know that the product rule holds for products of basis elements, i.e., that $D(x^i x^j) = D(x^i)x^j + x^i D(x^j)$ for each $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f = \sum_{i=1}^m f_i x^i$ and $g = \sum_{j=1}^n g_j x^j$. Then, by linearity of $D$,
$$
 D(fg) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n f_i g_j D(x^i x^j)
= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n f_i g_j (D(x^i)x^j + x^i D(x^j))
= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n f_i D(x^i) g_j x^j + \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n f_i x^i g_j D(x^j)
= (Df)g + f(Dg).
$$